# Add Color Animation to Mah:Tile

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, coloranimation

I'm Using [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) and I'm using a Tile Element which Is loaded with namespace 'MahCtrl'( `xmlns:MahCtrl="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls`). I want to apply `ColorAnimation` to the Tile on `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`.

Here is the xaml snippet I am Currently working on.

```
<UserControl xmlns:MahCtrl="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">
   <MahCtrl:Tile Cursor="Hand" Background="Transparent" Height="200" Width="210"HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">     
        <MahCtrl:Tile.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:0.200"   
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(MahCtrl:Tile.Background).Color" 
                                To="#fffccc" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
                                  Duration="0:0:0.250"   
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(MahCtrl:Tile.Background).Color" 
                                  To="#ffffff" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
       </MahCtrl:Tile.Triggers>
    </MahCtrl:Tile>
</UserControl>
```

In the debug section, When I Enter mouse into the Tile the following exception occurs

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve all property
>   references in the property path '(0).Color'. Verify that applicable
>   objects support the properties.'

I have tried Using `(Background).Color` and a lot of other combinations to `StoryBoard.TargetProperty` But this method works when `MahCtrl:Tile` element is wrapped with a stack panel and applying event triggers `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` triggers with target `(StackPanel.Background).Color` to the StackPanel. How can I target background property of `MahCtrl:Tile`

It would be a great help if someone can refer to a documentation regarding this topic

Thank you very much,

Comment: What is MahCtrl:Tile.Triggers? Is that part of a control template inside a style template? Can you show us the Style template for `{x:Type controls:Tile}`? Either way this would definitely be simpler and easier to extend starting from the default style template for that control.

Comment: It is defined inside `Tile` element (`MahCtrl:Tile`). I'm A beginner and not sure I'm doing it right. I've updated the code including tile component. thanks for your interest